# Springboot jetty web socket client : How to know relationship between onMessage(String) and onMessage(byte[])

Tags: java, spring, websocket, jetty

There is a web socket server who sends byte data after sending string data.
And the two data sent in turn are related to each other.

I could get data from the server like below.

```
    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessageString(Session session, String msg){
        System.out.println("getRemoteAddress1:"+session.getRemoteAddress());
        String vaHost = session.getRemoteAddress().toString().replaceAll("/", "");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("Got msg: %s%n",msg);
    }


    @OnWebSocketMessage
    public void onMessageBuffer(Session session, byte[] byteArray, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("onMessageBuffer");
        System.out.println("getRemoteAddress2:"+session.getRemoteAddress());
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("C:/files/ws/"+System.nanoTime()+".jpg"), byteArray);
    }
```

However, these two functions cannot determine the association between string data and byte data.
How can I correlate and process the data coming in turn from the web socket server?

Thank you all!

Comment: There's no relationship in the websocket protocol between messages.  All you can rely on is that messages are received in order that they were sent.  Perhaps you should just send all of the messages you get into a single point processing method of your own design? or go through a queue of your own? etc ...

Comment: I made global variable for containing string and byte array data like you said. Thank you again Joakim! You are the best:)